# Receiveing array of Images from CoreData

Tags: ios, arrays, image, core-data

I've created `NSManagedObject* imagesArrayData` that stores strings (paths) to images stored in the documents directory:

```
- (void)setImagesArray:(NSMutableArray *)imagesArray {
    NSMutableArray* newImagesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    int i = 1;
    for (UIImage* image in imagesArray) {
        //generate path to createdFile
        NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d", self.name, i];
        NSString* filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:fileName]; 
        //save image to disk
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        //add image path to CoreData
        [newImagesArray addObject:filePath];

        i++;
    }

    //set new value of imagesArray
    imagesArrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newImagesArray];
```

I am now not showing pathsToImages in header file, but property imagesArray:

```
 -(NSMutableArray*) imagesArray {
        NSMutableArray* images = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSArray* imagePaths = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:imagesArrayData];
        for (NSString* imagePath in imagePaths) {
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
            [images addObject:image];
        }
        return images;
```

The problem is, that whenever I want to get to `[imagesArray objectatIndex:xxx]`, the imagesArray getter is called, and it takes time to recreate the full array. When trying to switch fast between images, the UI slows down.
What would be the elegant way to overcome this problem? Maybe creating another array full of images and updating it from time to time? Maybe something else? Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is refactor your getter to lazily load the array. If it is already defined, simply return it. If not, build it:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) imagesArray 
{
  if (!_imagesArray)
  {
    NSMutableArray* _imagesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray* imagePaths = 
      [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: imagesArrayData];
    for (NSString* imagePath in imagePaths) 
    {
      UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
     [_imagesArray addObject:image];
  }
  return _imagesArray;
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean about updating an array of images from time to time.

If your array of image names changes you will need some method to respond to those changes.

Comment: Sounds easy and good way, but I receive error when typing _imagesArray - use of undeclared identifier.
I have atproperty (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* imagesArray; in my *.h file, but in *.m I use atdynamic imagesArray. I'm not sure, but when using atdynamic I cannot use "_variable" notation. When changed to self.imagesArray I go into infinite loop of imagesArray getters.

Comment: If you are using @dynamic then you need to create a private instance variable yourself called _imagesArray. Just add the declaration to your header file. And you are using "retain"? Why are you using manual reference counting? It should be "(nonatomic, strong)" if you are using ARC.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works nicely. I am not using retain. Thanks!

Comment: You said in your comment "I have @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* imagesArray;" That sure sounds like a property declared using retain to me!

Comment: My mistake from copy-pasting ;)

Comment: @izik461 You accepted this answer, so I assume it was useful to you.  In that case, you should also upvote the answer as well.

Comment: Done :) Thanks for the info.